# I want to open up my kitchen by taking down a load bearing brick wall

Tags: framing, beam, steel

The clear span would be 22ft plus what would have to sit on posts. I want a steel beem preferably because it would be exposed under the trusses. My question is what type I would need and what load bearing rate I will need. Not sure if I explained it correctly. Thanks for any help.

Comment: The first thing you need is an engineer to analyze what forces it would have to carry and where it could transfer them to. Which may involve reinforcing other structures  No Way anyone can advise you on this over the net.

Comment: What is this brick wall supporting? Are there a lower floors with the brick wall continuing down to the foundation? If so, is the whole brick wall getting removed? What does the foundation look like below where you intend to install these posts? The structure's dimensions and configuration perpendicular to the beam are important because such dimensions and configuration are necessary to compute loads.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no matter how well intentioned, a bunch of strangers on the internet is not the place to be getting structural engineering information. Pay an engineer to design the beam - it'll be far cheaper than rebuilding the house because the "by guess and by gosh" design work that came up here was insufficient and your insurance company refuses to pay.

Answer (score 6):

Taking out a load bearing brick wall is a very complex project. If done wrong it could undermine the soundness of the house. The first question should not be "what kind of beam do I need". but rather "is this even possible". You need to hire a qualified engineer to assess the current design and tell you if it's safe to proceed at all. If it is possible, hire a general contractor with experience doing this sort of thing.

If you are not sure what beam you need, it means you should definitely not try and do this yourself.